# You only have five

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, crossword-clues, metapuzzles

> 1: dim advantage in first French Expansion
> (4,5): Kiss
> Pain
> Boot
> City
> History
> Again
> Eat
> Avid
> (5,13,13,5,3,4)
>
> 2: undisturbed apartment
> ground hideout
> attach badge
> punch holder
>
> 1,3: advantage protect
> lady wrong
> extra raise
> prime month
> error pass
> overjoyed narrated

Hint:

> 2 is somewhat related to animals.

Hint #2:

> 4,5 are intended to give you a word(closely related or similar in meaning) for each clue.

Hint #3:

> 4,5 are supposed to be arranged in a word square. 2 gives you two different meanings for the same word.

Final Hint:

> Anyone thinking of Phrases yet?

Comment: I'd just like to confirm that it is `1,3` and not `1,5`... ?

Comment: @Phylyp 1,3 is not 1,5

Comment: Thanks Sid, I was barking up the wrong tree there. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer at the moment:

**1:**

> First line appears to be a cryptic clue for the word FADE: F(AD)E.

**2:**

> Each pair of words are two different definitions of another word:
>
>  undisturbed apartment **FLAT**
>  ground hideout **EARTH**
>  attach badge **PIN**
>  punch holder **HOOK**
>
>  All four can prefix the word **WORM** (animal-related, as suggested by one of the hints).

**1,3:**

> Each line appears to suggest a pair of words, where the second word is the first with a letter added to the front.
>
>  advantage protect **edge-*H*edge**
>  lady wrong **miss-*A*miss**
>  extra raise **other-*M*other** *(courtesy of CaptainPlanet in the comments)*
>  prime month **arch-*M*arch**
>  error pass **lapse-*E*lapse**
>  overjoyed narrated **elated-*R*elated**
>
>  The first letters spell out **HAMMER**.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: 'extra raise' might be rot13( bgure-zbgure )

Comment: I like it. I'll add it in a bit.

Comment: I've fixed the post with the correct, intended solution.

Comment: Very nice update on #2... but what does (SNQR NGGNPX JBEZ UNZZRE) mean, I wonder?

Comment: I think we have to figure out a common thread between them and use the numbers before the colons in some way. Think like a metapuzzle.

Answer (score 4):

**4, 5**: With the help of hint #3:

> Each word clues a four-letter word:
>
> ```
>     PECK Kiss            PAST History
>     ACHE Pain            ECHO Again
>     SHOE Boot            CHOW Eat
>     TOWN City            KEEN Avid
> ```
>
> These words can then be arranged in a magic square:
>
> ```
>     P E C K
>     A C H E
>     S H O E
>     T O W N
> ```
>
> Thanks to the observant commenters hagfy and Phylyp, who saw that the letters at positions (5, 13, 13, 5, 3, 4) spell **ATTACK**.

Comment: If you take the letters indicated by the numbers at the end of the clue, you get rot13(NGGNPX).

Comment: Letters (5,13,13,5,3,4) in the word square spell out ROT13(NGGNPX) , ninja'd by @hagfy

Comment: Thanks to both of you. How trivial. (And how embarrassing not to have seen it.)

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I have seriously messed up on difficulty-level of this puzzle. Also, many puzzlers have said how the puzzle seems underclued(which it probably is). So, I have decided to self-answer this.

SKOG and M Oehm have got the sub-puzzles right. Our answers are:

> FADE
>  ATTACK
>  WORM
>  HAMMER.

Next for the meta:

> All this words can be attached with the a body part to get another word/phrase. That is,
>  BRAIN Fade
>  HEART Attack
>  HammerTOE
>  LUNGWORM

Next,

> Taking the letters as shown by the numbering in the question and then an anagram gives us BUTTER which by the same relation, gives the final answer as **FINGERS**(which fits the title).

Comment: I've never heard *any* of these phrases except the second one.